# Problems by scrolling in recyclerview with progressbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I'm running at the moment into problems with my recyclerview when I scrolling fast down and the progressbar is visible (see the video). 
The progressbar shows on other items.

How can I fix it or is that a problem by the recyclerview?

[Link to the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76ytjQx8wPqU2NtaG1xT2JfbTA/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: do you hide this progress bar on other views? Be aware that views are reused, and if in one `onBindViewHolder` you set view visibility VISIBLE then it will remains in other items.

Comment: @RadekJ yep they are hidden in the onbindviewholder and also in the viewholder